# Open an executable with a parameter?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to open putty with my server data loaded through a batch file.

I tried `start "OVH" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe -ssh username@ip.address -pw password"`, and that did not work; however, when I go to \PuTTY, `putty.exe -ssh username@ip.address -pw password` does work.

What is the simplest, fastest, most cut-and-dry way to correct my syntax?

Comment: Why does it not work? Which error do you get. Did you try "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh username@ip.address -pw password ?

Comment: @Hennes That worked, if you want to post it as an answer.

Comment: Will do. Rather surprised since I did not research it nor do I have much experience with windows shortcuts. It just seems the way I always did things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit "OVH.bat" to: 
`start "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh username@ip.address -pw password"`

That starts the program `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe` with the arguments `-ssh username@ip.address -pw password`.